# Looking for a variable and all characters behind the text

Tags: python, variables

I have a code that looks for a file and takes the last time saved (modified) and then compares it with a new time. If a difference was found it will pop up a notification.

But Spreadsheet March.xlsx name can change to (example) Spreadsheet March 123.xlsx and I'm looking for something like in excel with adding * at the end so it will include everything behind the SpreadsheetPath variable.

```
import os.path, time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier


SpreadsheetPath = "X\Spreadsheet March.xlsx"
Spreadsheet_OldTime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(SpreadsheetPath))

def notif(file):
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast(file, file + " has been saved")

while True:
    print("Comparing Spreadsheet Time - " + Spreadsheet_OldTime[11:19] + " and " + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(SpreadsheetPath))[11:19])
    if Spreadsheet_OldTime != time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(SpreadsheetPath)):
        notif("Spreadsheet")
        Spreadsheet_OldTime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(SpreadsheetPath))
        print("Notification Pushed")
    else:
        print("No difference found...")
        print("Sleeping for 10 seconds\n")
        time.sleep(10)
```

I've tried to google it, but unfortunately couldn't find a solution that would be simple and easy

Comment: You want to get the path of everyfile whose name is in the format `Spreadsheet March xxxx.xlsx`? If yes then try using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to find pathnames matching a pattern you provide. From the library page:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've used glob

```
import glob
import time
import os.path

path = glob.glob('W:\Spreadsheet March*')
x = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(*path))

print(x)
```